# Proving an inequality involving a function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, monotone-functions

Suppose $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x,y): X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be non-decreasing in both arguments. Further, suppose that $x_{2}\geq x_{1}$ and $y_{2}\geq y_{1}$. I am trying to prove (though I am not entirely sure it holds) that the above assumptions imply that $f(x_{2}, y_{2}) - f(x_{1}, y_{2}) \geq f(x_{2}, y_{1}) - f(x_{1}, y_{1})$.

I have first tried to come up with counterexamples, but have not found any yet. Then I have tried to prove it directly, that is by deriving it directly from the assumptions, but I have not succeeded. I have also tried to show that the contrapositive statement will yield a contradiction, but I have only been successful in showing that it yields contradictions in specific counterexamples, and not in the general case. As an example, I have been able to show that if $f(x_{2}, y_{2}) - f(x_{1}, y_{2}) < f(x_{2}, y_{1}) - f(x_{1}, y_{1})$, then letting $f(x,y)=x+y$ and setting $y_{1}=y_{2} = 0$ yields a contradiction, namely that $x_{2} - x_{1} < x_{2} - x_{1}$. Hence, this inequality cannot hold in general. I still have not been able to show that it leads to a contradiction in the general case.

Any help on proving/disproving in the statement would be much appreciated. The reason I want to prove/disprove the statement is that if it turns out to be true, it will help me understand the proof of a lemma (lemma 2.1.5) in the book An Introduction to Copulas by Roger B. Nelsen.

Thanks in advance to all that took the time to read this post.

Comment: Take $f(x,y)=\frac{-1}{x+y}$.

Comment: @PNDas thanks for the comment! I cannot see that this works when I try it. Maybe I am doing something wrong. It seems to yield an expression that could both satisfy and not satisfy the inequality in general.

Comment: @PNDas Could you please make it clear which values you have picked for $x_{1}, x_{2}, y_{1}, y_{2}$, respectively? I do not follow your last comment. Thanks in advance

Comment: $x_1=y_1=1,x_2=y_2=2$

Comment: @PNDas Thanks. If I have calculated correctly this satisfies the inequality I am trying to prove as it yields $\frac{-1}{12}\geq \frac{-1}{6}$. However, this does not help me prove the inequality, nor does it disprove it. Did I misunderstand you in any way?

Comment: Are you sure?, my function is $\frac{-1}{x+y}$ not $\frac{1}{x+y}$. $\frac{-1}{4}-\frac{-1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}.$Similarly other one is $\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: @PNDas of course! You're right. Sorry for that mistake. And thank you so much for your help!